# Passing a returned value to an anonymous class

Tags: java

I am attempting to pass the return value from scheduling a task into an anonymous class, but I am running into trouble. If I set the return value to a final variable, it says it is not initialized:

```
/* Not initialized */
final BukkitTask task = Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskTimer(plugin, new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        /* irrelevant code */
        task.cancel();
    }

}, 0L, 20L);
```

I have also attempted passing a variable by calling a method within the anonymous class, however it changes the return type to void and therefore I cannot pass a proper value:

```
BukkitTask temp = null;
/* Returns void */
temp = Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskTimer(plugin, new Runnable() {

    private BukkitTask task;

    public void initTask(BukkitTask task) {
        this.task = task;
    }

    public void run() {
        /* irrelevant code */
        task.cancel();
    }

}.initTask(temp), 0L, 20L);
```

How can I pass a returned value into an anonymous class within the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define this class

```
class Box<T> {
    public volatile T value;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
final Box<BukkitTask> taskBox = new Box<BukkitTask>();
taskBox.value = Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskTimer(plugin, new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        /* irrelevant code */
        taskBox.value.cancel();
    }
}, 0L, 20L);
```

However, `taskBox.value` in `run` could still be `null` depending on when `runTaskTimer` actually executes the runnable.

Comment: Awesome solution as well!

Comment: Hm, so then how could I avoid a `null` value being passed? The volatile would help with reading the newest value, but would the only guarantee be possibly delaying the task slightly (the first passed long)?

Comment: I don't know what `runTaskTimer` does. If it only runs the runnable **after** it returns, all is well. If it starts running it before returning, but does so on a different thread, you could make `taskBox` a future instead of `Box` and wait for it in `run`.

Comment: This seems right, it works with `Future` and I believe that tasks do return before execution. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

My idea, which might sound stupid, would be to create a global variable to which you assign the return value.  Then, have a static method that would return this value to you in the anonymous class.

Comment: My overall stipulation is that if I end up with more than one runnable going at a time, then the second would overwrite the first, which would not be good.

Comment: Then have a `Vector` of return values. Number each of your runnables so that every anonymous class accesses only the corresponding value of the `Vector`. Simple ? Vectors are inherently synchronized so no issues of `synchronized` block or method. OK ? =)

Comment: Rather than using Vector (because of the synchronization on operations), I attempted a `Deque` but that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: Vector should guarantee thread safety for you. Vector operations are thread safe.

Comment: The issue isn't thread safety, but mainly guaranteeing that a global variable isn't overwritten *and* that I can get the proper return value before the task is executed.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have figured out an answer rather quickly!

You can change the return type of the `init` method, and then it will return the proper values for the code!:

```
BukkitTask task = null;
task = Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskTimer(plugin, new Runnable() {

    private BukkitTask task;

    public Runnable initTask(BukkitTask task) {
        this.task = task;
        return this;
    }

    public void run() {
        /* irrelevant code */
        task.cancel();
    }
}.initTask(task), 0L, 20L);
```

Comment: Doesn't this just set the task in the runnable to `null`? Pretty sure that `initTask` is executed before `runTaskTimer` returns, so the outer `task` will still be `null`.

Comment: @TobiasBrandt you are correct, and it seems the only way to fix that is a switcher statement of `public Runnable swap(Runnable temp)` that would set a global variable anyhow, so I suppose @LittleChild has a better overall solution.

Comment: see my answer on how to avoid a global variable

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what are you trying to do. Would `Callable` instead of `Runnable` solve the problem? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html

Comment: I attempted to solve it this way earlier, however the issue was passing the correct value to the callable within the runnable, which wasn't possible since I couldn't get the value in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

see this example

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Object objectA[] = new String[1];

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        private A refA = null;
        public void run() {
            objectA[0] = "Hello World or your object";
        }
    }).start();;

    while (objectA[0] == null){

    }
    System.out.println(objectA[0]);
}
```

Comment: I think you missed the question by a slight amount: The idea was passing the return value of the anonymous class into itself (in a sense)